# How do I log to console when running locally, and log to rolling log file when running on the server using log4j2?

Tags: logging, log4j2

Hello my current project requires me to, as the title suggests, log to the console when, a developer is running the application on their machine , and log to a rolling log file when the application is running on the server. So far I've created a log4j2.properties file (see below) and it logs to both the console and rolling log file just fine. I've researched and I have seen examples on the Apache website, and others, using a Routing appender, but all of the examples have used a log4j2.xml file. Is it possible to create this using a log4j2.properties file? Thank you.

```
status = error
dest = err
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = C:\\MyApplications\\ExampleApplication\\Example.log

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

#LOG TO CONSOLE 
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{1} - %m%n
appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.console.filter.threshold.level = debug

#LOG TO ROLLING FILE
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = ExampleLogBackup-%d{MM-dd-yy}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{1} - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 10
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=1MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20
logger.rolling.name = com.myapp.example
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = true
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below lines in your properties configuration file after `RollingFileAppender` configuration -

```
appender.routing.type = Routing
appender.routing.name = routingLogger
appender.routing.script.type = Script
appender.routing.script.name = RoutingCondition
appender.routing.script.language = JavaScript
# Condition is - if isLocalMachine VM argument is true (-DisLocalMachine=true), 
# then log messages in console else log messages in file.
appender.routing.script.value = var imports = new JavaImporter(java.lang);                                  \
                                with (imports) {                                                            \
                                    System.getProperty("isLocalMachine") == "true" ? "console" : "file";    \
                                }
appender.routing.routes.type = Routes
appender.routing.routes.route1.type = Route
appender.routing.routes.route1.ref = STDOUT
appender.routing.routes.route1.key = console
appender.routing.routes.route2.type = Route
appender.routing.routes.route2.ref = RollingFile
appender.routing.routes.route2.key = file
```

then use this `RoutingAppender` in `Logger` -

```
logger.rolling.appenderRef.routing.ref = routingLogger
```

Same for `RootLogger` -

```
rootLogger.appenderRef.routing.ref = routingLogger
```

Routing of logs will be done based on the value of `isLocalMachine VM argument`. if `isLocalMachine VM argument` is `true` (`-DisLocalMachine=true`), then log messages in console else log messages in file.

So, in your local development environment, you can set this `VM argument` with `true` value to enabling logging in console. For Server, no need to set this `VM argument`.

Comment: This is working just as you described. Thank you so much! :D

Comment: Hi Vikas, could you please guide me on how you found this answer? Did you find some documentation, or is this from experience? Thank you

Comment: @pukimonstr there is almost no documentation for properties configuration. It is just sometimes, you have to try, look into the source code, debug to identify problem solution.